# Find a maximal ideal in $F_7[x]/(x^2+5)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

$F_p=Z/(pZ)$

I'm stuck at this problem. I tried to find the irreducible factorisation of $x^2+5$, but that didn't help too much. Any ideas? and also could anyone explain the general philosophy with regard to solving this kind of problem?

Comment: Hint: over $F_7$ we have $x^2+5=x^2-9$.

Comment: @David Okay. So my factorisation turns out to be $(x+3)(x-3)$. But this is where I seem to have stuck upon. Edit: sorry I made a silly mistake.

Comment: @David Should I invoke the Chinese remainder theorem here?

Comment: since your ring is actually an algebra over $\mathbb{F}_7$ with dimesion $2$. It actually suffices to find a nonzero zero divisor. Maybe that helps (but I would also make sure you understand why what I just said holds)

Comment: @Enkidu I'm sorry I didn't quite catch that. Could you explain why is this? I suppose x+3 and x-3 are the nonzero zero divisor we are looking for? I don't see why (x+3) should be maximal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry, but the further explanation in the comments would actually give the solution, so I just write it here.]

We know for that $\mathbb{F}_7[x]/(x^2+5)$ some things:

1.$(x^2+5)=(x^2-9)=(x-3)(x+3)$

2.$\mathbb{F}_7[x]/(x^2+5)\cong \mathbb{F}_7 \oplus [x]\mathbb{F}_7$ as vectorspaces.

3.The above isomorphism makes $\mathbb{F}_7[x]/(x^2+5)$ into a $\mathbb{F}_7$ algebra.

Now we get that any ideal is a sub-$\mathbb{F}_7$-vectorspace of $\mathbb{F}_7[x]/(x^2+5)$ not containing $1$ in particular it cannot contain any element of $\mathbb{F}_7 \hookrightarrow \mathbb{F}_7[x]/(x^2+5)$. Now for dimensionreasons this means that our maximal ideal has maximal dimension one, which means that any nontrivial ideal is already maximal, so it suffices to find a nontrivial nonunit element and take the ideal generated by it. So a nontrivial zero-devisor has to do the trick of which we clearly already have 2 obvious possible choices: $(x-3)$ and $(x+3)$.

And we are done, actually no proper algebra involved, only linear algebra.